# 10 threads in a single program or 1 thread program ran 10 times (C++)?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I am wondering whether there is any difference in performance in running a single program (exe) with 10 different threads or running the program with a single thread 10 times in parallel (starting it from a .bat file) assuming the work done is the same and only the number of threads spawned by the program change?

I am developing a client/server communication program and want to test it for throughput. I'm currently learning about parallel programming and threading as wasn't sure how Windows would handle the above scenario. Will the scheduler schedule work the same way for both scenarios? Will there be a performance difference?

The machine the program is running on has 4 threads.

Comment: unfortunately programs usually cannot be parallelized such that all workload can be evenly distributed among threads. Consider i/o, if the program needs input from a file, you need to read this input 4 times (with 4 single threaded) or somehow share the input among the threads

Comment: Running the program 10 times means you get 10 processes. Running one program with 10 threads means you get 1 process with 10 threads. Threads have been introduced as "light-weight processes" to lower the OS overhead/load for concurrent execution. So, theoretically one process with 10 threads might be faster but this, of course, very depends how the program is implemented and if the threads may run really concurrently without any other synchronization than that if you start 10 processes with one thread...

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is really dependent on both your OS and your processor. At an abstract level I would guess that threads share the same memory space so your processor does not have to remap it when context switching, but the actual impact of that is anyone's guess.

Comment: And not just the OS and processor. There's also the runtime, and the program itself. For example, a garbage collector might work better for ten processes than a single process. Or it might be the reverse. There's just too many variables to allow saying anything beyond "threads were _designed_ to be lighter-weight than processes; sometimes that helps performance, sometimes it kills it".

Comment: do you know [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) ? Its a bit oversimplifying but a good starting point to understand what you can expect from utilizing more threads

Comment: Thank you for the reponses. I do know Amdahl's law, learnt about it a month ago ish. I appreciate that this is quite tricky to tell and there isn't really a set answer. As @Scheff mentioned maybe the fact that threads are really just "light-weight" processes means the operating system is able to deal with them quicker. Luaan pretty much said the same thing as Scheff. Thanks guys!

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 For the most part I would apply the same problems to both multiple threads and *processes*. If I can't find something an extra N threads can do efficiently, what are an extra N processes meant to do?

Comment: @FireLancer good point. Should have read the question more carefully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threads are slightly lighter weight than processes as there are many things a process gets it's own copy of. Especially when you compare the time it takes to start a new thread, vs starting a new process (from scratch, `fork` where available also avoids a lot of costs). Although in either case you can generally get even better performance using a worker pool where possible rather than starting and stopping fresh processes/threads.

The other major difference is that threads by default all share the same memory while processes get their own and need to communicate through more explicit means (which may include blocks of *shared memory*). This might make it easier for a threaded solution to avoid copying data, but this is also one of the dangers of multithreaded programming when care is not taken in how they use the shared memory/objects.

Also there may be API's that are more orientated around a single process. For example on Windows there is IO Completion Ports which basically works on the idea of having many in-progress IO operations for different files, sockets, etc. with multiple threads (but generally far less than the number of files/sockets) handling the results as they become available through a `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` loop.

Comment: @bluiska no problem. Also I just had a thought on API usage which can influence designs